# PHP not working CentOS 6 after yum update

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I had some problems running `yum update` and did the followingn steps to make it work:

1. `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 -y remove memcached` - this simply removed memcached, one of the packages giving errors
2. `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 -y remove php-pear` - this removed more than I bargained for..

> Running Transaction   Erasing    : phpMyAdmin-4.0.4-1.el6.remi.noarch 
>   1/28  waarschuwing: /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf saved as
>   /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.rpmsave   Erasing    :
>   php-pecl-memcached-2.1.0-6.el6.remi.5.x86_64
>   2/28    Erasing    :
>   php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.2-0.5.git3b8ab7e.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   3/28    Erasing    : php-php-gettext-1.0.11-4.el6.remi.noarch
>   4/28    Erasing    : php-pecl-mongo-1.4.1-1.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   5/28    Erasing    :
>   php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.3.svn313074.el6.remi.5.x86_64
>   6/28    Erasing    : php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   7/28    Erasing    :
>   php-pecl-apc-3.1.15-0.3.svn329913.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   8/28    Erasing    : php-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   9/28    Erasing    : php-gmp-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   10/28    Erasing    : php-mysqlnd-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   11/28    Erasing    : php-recode-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   12/28    Erasing    : php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.0.049-1.el6.noarch
>   13/28    Erasing    : php-tcpdf-6.0.049-1.el6.noarch
>   14/28    Erasing    : php-bcmath-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   15/28    Erasing    : php-gd-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   16/28    Erasing    : php-mbstring-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   17/28    Erasing    : php-mcrypt-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   18/28    Erasing    : php-tidy-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   19/28    Erasing    : php-pgsql-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   20/28    Erasing    : php-pdo-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   21/28    Erasing    : php-intl-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   22/28    Erasing    : php-cli-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   23/28    Erasing    : php-process-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   24/28    Erasing    : php-xml-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   25/28    Erasing    : php-common-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   26/28  waarschuwing: /etc/php.ini saved as /etc/php.ini.rpmsave
>   Erasing    : php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.1-2.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   27/28    Erasing    : 1:php-pear-1.9.5-10.el6.remi.noarch
>   28/28  /usr/bin/pecl: regel 2: /usr/bin/php: Bestand of map bestaat
>   niet /usr/bin/pecl: regel 2: exec: Kan /usr/bin/php niet uitvoeren:
>   Bestand of map bestaat niet waarschuwing: /etc/pear.conf saved as
>   /etc/pear.conf.rpmsave   Verifying  :
>   php-bcmath-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   1/28    Verifying  : php-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   2/28    Verifying  :
>   php-pecl-apc-3.1.15-0.3.svn329913.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   3/28    Verifying  : php-php-gettext-1.0.11-4.el6.remi.noarch
>   4/28    Verifying  : php-mbstring-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   5/28    Verifying  : php-intl-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   6/28    Verifying  : phpMyAdmin-4.0.4-1.el6.remi.noarch
>   7/28    Verifying  : php-tcpdf-6.0.049-1.el6.noarch
>   8/28    Verifying  : php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.0.049-1.el6.noarch 
>   9/28    Verifying  : php-recode-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   10/28    Verifying  : php-mcrypt-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   11/28    Verifying  : php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   12/28    Verifying  : php-common-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   13/28    Verifying  : php-cli-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   14/28    Verifying  : 1:php-pear-1.9.5-10.el6.remi.noarch
>   15/28    Verifying  :
>   php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.3.svn313074.el6.remi.5.x86_64
>   16/28    Verifying  : php-xml-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   17/28    Verifying  : php-pecl-mongo-1.4.1-1.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   18/28    Verifying  : php-tidy-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   19/28    Verifying  : php-pgsql-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   20/28    Verifying  : php-pdo-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   21/28    Verifying  : php-process-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   22/28    Verifying  :
>   php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.2-0.5.git3b8ab7e.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   23/28    Verifying  : php-pecl-memcached-2.1.0-6.el6.remi.5.x86_64
>   24/28    Verifying  : php-gd-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   25/28    Verifying  : php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.1-2.el6.remi.1.x86_64
>   26/28    Verifying  : php-gmp-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   27/28    Verifying  : php-mysqlnd-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64
>   28/28
>
> Removed:   php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.5-10.el6.remi
>
> Dependency Removed:   php.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-cli.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-common.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-gd.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-gmp.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-intl.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-pecl-apc.x86_64 0:3.1.15-0.3.svn329913.el6.remi.1
>   php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 0:1.1.2-0.5.git3b8ab7e.el6.remi.1
>   php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.1-2.el6.remi.1
>   php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-1.el6.remi.1
>   php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:2.1.0-6.el6.remi.5
>   php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6.remi.1
>   php-pecl-sqlite.x86_64 0:2.0.0-0.3.svn313074.el6.remi.5
>   php-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-4.el6.remi
>   php-process.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-recode.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.0.049-1.el6
>   php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.0.049-1.el6
>   php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   php-xml.x86_64 0:5.5.0-1.el6.remi
>   phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.4-1.el6.remi

3. `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi update` - This only updated mysql, not apache or php
4. `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pear` - this installed php again, but version 5.4.40

> Install       5 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 5.4 M Installed size: 21 M Is this ok [y/N]: y
>   Downloading Packages: (1/5): php-cli-5.4.40-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
>   | 3.9 MB     00:00      (2/5): php-common-5.4.40-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
>   | 959 kB     00:00      (3/5): php-pear-1.9.5-10.el6.remi.noarch.rpm
>   | 357 kB     00:00      (4/5):
>   php-process-5.4.40-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm                             |
>   64 kB     00:00      (5/5): php-xml-5.4.40-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
>   | 174 kB     00:00

5. `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update` - this updated php to version 5.5.24, which is what I want

> Dependency Installed:   php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.7-1.el6.remi.5.5
>   php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.12.5-1.el6.remi.5.5
>
> Updated:   php-cli.x86_64 0:5.5.24-1.el6.remi
>   php-common.x86_64 0:5.5.24-1.el6.remi             php-process.x86_64
>   0:5.5.24-1.el6.remi           php-xml.x86_64 0:5.5.24-1.el6.remi

Then I've restarted apache and mysql.

Now when I go to any of the (Wordpress) websites on this server, they either display the Apache 2 Test Page or the contents of index.php as plain text (no php execution).

I looked around on Stackoverflow and found some stuff on adding:
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

But unfortunately that file does not exist.
locate libphp5.so gives
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so but
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
gives an error when restarting apache..

I think I've removed more php packages than intended, but I'm not sure which packages are missing and should be installed again. Can anyone point me in the right direction? And tell me wether I should reinstall apache or not? I'd rather not lose any config..

Comment: "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so gives an error when restarting apache.." What error does it give when you restart apache?

Comment: `Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director`

I think I should somehow install a package or something that inserts php5 in apache config and creates the libphp5.so in the proper place..

Comment: In all the docs I've seen there should be a `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` file, but that's also missing

Comment: try running yum install php --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved it somehow. I removed and (re)installed everything from httpd, php, php-common, php-cli, php-pear, php-mysql and also installed httpd-devel and php-devel

In this process I also manually created a `php.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`

I also ran this from the [centos forums](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=28672):
rpm -qa 'php*'
rpm -V php

Eventually the correct php.conf was created in this process and after restarting apache everything is working again.

Answer (score -1):

as stated in the error-message, there's an issue because it can not access the 'shared object file'. This can happen after installing new stuff and not running ldconfig.
So, stop httpd, install your php modules and run ldconfig, then restart apache.

```
# ldconfig
# apachectl start
```

Comment: After running ldconfig and re-adding 
`LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` or `LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` (tried both) it all gives the same error (as already posted above) when trying to restart httpd.

Comment: The weird thing is that the symlink from `/etc/httpd/modules` goes correctly to `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules`

`ls -al /etc/httpd/modules/` reveals all kinds of mods, but no php
`ls -al /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/` reveals exactly the same as the above
`locate libphp5.so` outputs: `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`, which is the same friggin directory?!